# Prevent going to top of page after link click

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application i have a partial view with this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="resendCode()" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Resend</a>
```

On the View i have the **resendCode()** function:

```
 function resendCode() {

        var newEmail= $('#hdnEmail').val();
        $.getJSON("/User/ResendCode", { email: newEmail}, function (data) {
            showMessage(data.Message);
        });
    };
```

But this partial view stays on the botton of the View, and always after i click on the href link the focus goes to the top of the page. Why thats happen and how to prevent it?

If i change the `<a href` tag to `<input type="button" onclick="resendCode()" value="Resend" />` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<a href="#" onclick="resendCode(); return false;" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Resend</a>
```

to prevent the scrolling

Comment: or `onclick="event.preventDefault(); resendCode();"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put return false;
It should prevent the method to do his default behavior and will not go to the anchor

```
function resendCode() {

        var newEmail= $('#hdnEmail').val();
        $.getJSON("/User/ResendCode", { email: newEmail}, function (data) {
            showMessage(data.Message);
        });
        return false;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="resendCode(event)" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Resend</a>
```

And change function definition to:

```
 function resendCode(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var newEmail= $('#hdnEmail').val();
    $.getJSON("/User/ResendCode", { email: newEmail}, function (data) {
        showMessage(data.Message);
    });
};
```

Notice that, we are passing 'event' object as a parameter to the function which will be 'click' in this case.
Then we are using jQuery's 'preventDefault' method which prevents the default action of the event.
In your HTML you are using href="#" which causes a page to jump to top after user clicks on the link. This can be avoided by calling jQuery's preventDefault().

Read More:
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/